# Slice efficiently pandas datetime index by a specific time

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most efficient way to get all the rows of a dataframe with a specific time?
For instance, if I create the following DataFrame,

```
df = DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2016-04-01',freq='min'))
```

and then try to get all the rows with a 3pm time:

```
%timeit df[df.index.time == time(15,0)]
1 loops, best of 3: 9.29 s per loop
```

it works but it is very slow.

Also, what about efficiently slicing between two specific times ?

```
%timeit df[(df.index.time >= time(15,0)) & (df.index.time <= time(16,0))]
1 loops, best of 3: 18.7 s per loop
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`at_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at_time.html) and [`between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
print df.at_time('15:00')

print df.between_time(start_time='15:00', end_time='16:00')
```

Comment: takes less than 200ms each, brilliant!

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
df.loc[df.index.hour == 15]
```